# Error handling to return error object in services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

This is CreateSubscription service class. I put this logic in service because there are api calls and some data insertion occurs.
(This is simplified version.)

This class is called basically from controller, and I need to handle errors there. 
However the question is how can I triger errors with **user.erros** object instead of full_messages, so that I can iterate the errors and create error response with JSON.

***{
  "error": "Uuid can't be blank, Name can't be blank, and Email is invalid"
}***

to

***{
  "errors": [
    {
      "uuid": [
        "can't be blank"
      ],"name" : ["can't be blank"]..
    }
  ]
}***

**services/create_subscription.rb**

```
class CreateSubscription
  class UserCreateError < StandardError; end

  def self.call(plan, user_info:)
    subscription = nil
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      user = CreateUser.call(user_info)
      raise UserCreateError.new(user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence) unless user.valid?
```

**service/create_user.rb**

```
class CreateUser
  def self.call(payment_info)
    uuid = payment_info[:uuid]
    name = payment_info[:name]
    email = payment_info[:email]

    user = User.find_by(uuid: uuid)
    return user if user.present?

    user = User.create(
      uuid: uuid,
      name: name,
      email: email
    )
    user
  end
end
```

## UPDATE

controller/subscriptions_controller.rb

```
 def create
      # Some logic ....
      rescue CreateSubscription::UserCreateError => e
        # TODO: This should be an array, not only each one
        render json: { error: e.message }, status: :bad_request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `messages` ([see the docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html)):

```
user = User.create
user.save # => false
user.errors.messages # => {uuid: ["cannot be blank"], name: ["cannot be blank"]}
```

In addition you can add your own key to make a "root":

```
{errors: user.errors.messages}
```

UPDATE:

You really should consider refactoring your code.
You're using Exception as a control flow.. ([See this why should not](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why))

To replace this you can use [custom validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators).

Then you can call it like this in your controller:

```
def create
  user = User.new(<params>)
  if user.save
    # do whatever you like, most likely a redirect
  else
    render json: { errors: user.errors.messages }, status: bad_request
  end
end
```

This should render a json like this:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "uuid": [
      "can't be blank"
    ]
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This does work. Thanks. However I wonder why it outputs with backslashes "error": "{:uuid=>[\"can't be blank\"].

Comment: Can you add it to your question how you're using it?

Comment: Updated. I need to add iterator to crate for each, but it's basically outputs the errors in JSON format.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I'd better to error handling. With custom validator, I can check like '@model_name.errors.blank?' and then check if there are some errors or not, right?

Comment: One more question, actually my service class dealing with few nested database insertions. Can you suggest how I can pass errors in models to controller efficiently? The logic is like <Controller> <=> <Service> <=> <Model>.